# Создание XSL из XML. Особенность работы при наличии пространств имен

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl

Имеется документ xml, в тегах которого есть много зависимостей:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ZoneToGKN
  xmlns:Simple1="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/simple-types/1.0"
  xmlns:adrInp2="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/address-input/6.0.1"
  xmlns:tns="urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/supplementary/commons/1.0.1"
  xmlns:Org4="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/organization/4.0.1"
  xmlns:Person1="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/person/5.0.2"
  xmlns:Gov5="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/governance/5.0.1"
  xmlns:Simple4="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/simple-types/4.1.1"
  xmlns:dAp1="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/directories/applied-file/1.0.1"
  xmlns:dAl3="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/directories/all-documents/3.0.2"
  xmlns:dEcZ1="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/directories/economic-zone/1.0.1"
  xmlns:Sen5="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/sender/5.0.1"
  xmlns:DocI3="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/document-info/5.0.1"
  xmlns:Simple10="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/simple-types/10.0.1"
  xmlns="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/incoming/zone-to-gkn/5.0.8"
  xmlns:zone4="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/zone/4.2.2"
  NameSoftware="Полигон Про"
  VersionSoftware="5.1.0.11"
  GUID="8b4470f6-8543-447f-bb63-48df27c31806"
>
  <Title>
    <DocI3:CodeDocument>558221040000</DocI3:CodeDocument>
    <DocI3:Number>б/н</DocI3:Number>
    <DocI3:Date>2019-11-20</DocI3:Date>
    <DocI3:IssueOrgan>Комитет по охране объектов культурного наследия Ростовской области</DocI3:IssueOrgan>
  </Title>
...
</ZoneToGKN>
```

Моя задача сформировать xsl документ для преобразования xml в таблицу.

Все мои попытки не принесли результата

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:Simple1="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/simple-types/1.0"
  xmlns:adrInp2="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/address-input/6.0.1"
  xmlns:tns="urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/supplementary/commons/1.0.1"
  xmlns:Org4="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/organization/4.0.1"
  xmlns:Person1="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/person/5.0.2"
  xmlns:Gov5="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/governance/5.0.1"
  xmlns:Simple4="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/simple-types/4.1.1"
  xmlns:dAp1="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/directories/applied-file/1.0.1"
  xmlns:dAl3="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/directories/all-documents/3.0.2"
  xmlns:dEcZ1="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/directories/economic-zone/1.0.1"
  xmlns:Sen5="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/sender/5.0.1"
  xmlns:DocI3="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/document-info/5.0.1"
  xmlns:Simple10="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/simple-types/10.0.1"
  xmlns="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/incoming/zone-to-gkn/5.0.8"
  xmlns:zone4="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/zone/4.2.2">
    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <html>
            <head>
                <style type="text/css">
                    table { border-collapse: collapse; }
                    td, th { padding: 3px; border: 1px solid black; }
                    th { background: #9acd32; }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>...</th>
                        <th>...</th>
                        <th>...</th>
                        <th>...</th>
                        <th>...</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ZoneToGKN/Title" mode="all"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Title" mode="all">
        <!-- Основная геометрия и многоконтурные объекты-->
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="DocI3:Date" /></td>
            <td>Main</td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Подобный способ отлично работает на документах без DocI3:CodeDocument зависимостей.
Подскажите, что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот эта строка

```xml
xmlns="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/incoming/zone-to-gkn/5.0.8"
```

говорит, что все дочерние элементы и этот элемент, у которых не указан префикс пространства имена, находятся в пространстве имен `urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/incoming/zone-to-gkn/5.0.8`

Это интуитивно понятно для XML, а вот для XSL происходит следующее:

Вы пишете

```xsl
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/incoming/zone-to-gkn/5.0.8">
  <html>
    <xsl:value-of select="ZoneTKG"/>
  </html>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Вы объявляете три элемента (XSL - это подмножество XML)

- `stylesheet` в пространстве имен `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`
- `html` в пространстве имен `urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/incoming/zone-to-gkn/5.0.8`
- `value-of` в пространстве имен `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`

При этом выборка элемента `ZoneTKG` происходит не из пространства имен по умолчанию, а их пустого пространства имен.

Что нужно сделать:

1. В xsl убрать пространство имен по умолчанию, а вместо этого определить префикс пространства имен

   ```xsl
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:ztg="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/incoming/zone-to-gkn/5.0.8">
   ```

   имя префикса может быть любым и ого никак не коррелирует с префиксами исходного XML. Главное что оно должно быть уникальным в пределах текущего документа.
2. Обращение ко всем элементам, которые в исходном XML находятся в пространстве имен по умолчанию нужно осуществлять с применением этого префикса

   ```xsl
   <xsl:apply-templates select="ztg:ZoneToGKN/ztg:Title" mode="all"/>

   <xsl:template match="ztg:Title" mode="all">
     ............
   </xsl:template>
   ```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Это помогло. Теперь нужно вчитаться, чтобы понять смысл этой операции =)

Comment: Хороший ответ, +1 с моей стороны!